# What is the best way to change the class that is called by an inherited method after class initialization in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I am attempting to create a parallel class structure in two separate modules, where the methods of classes in one module e.g. `source.py` are registered to identically named modules in `receiving.py` via inheritance.

My issue is that if an inherited method in `receiving.py` calls another class in the module, it will point back to the class in `source.py`, and not in `receiving.py`. I understand this is expected, but how can I change which class the method points to during or after mapping, so the method in the `receiving.py` class will call the class from `receiving.py`.

Here is a schematic to help illustrate the problem. [schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fykld.jpg)

**Minimally sufficient example**:

`source.py`

```py
class Foo:
    origin = 'src'
    
    @classmethod
    def get_origin(cls):
        return cls.origin
    
    @classmethod
    def get_origin_bar(cls):
        return Bar.origin
                    
class Bar:
    origin = 'src'
```

`receiving.py`

```py
class Tag:
    pass

class Foo(Tag):
    origin = 'rec'

                    
class Bar(Tag):
    origin = 'rec'
```

```py
def register_bases(base, module):
    """
    Recursive function that adds __bases__ from DataJoint Tables in base to matching classes in module.
    :param base (module): source module with classes to. 
    :param module (module): mapping between classes and methods
    """
    for name in dir(base):
        base_cls = getattr(base, name)
        module_cls = getattr(module, name) if hasattr(module, name) else None
        if module_cls and inspect.isclass(module_cls) and issubclass(module_cls, receiving.Tag):
            assert base_cls not in module_cls.__bases__, f'Class "{name}" of base already in __base__ of module.'
            module_cls.__bases__ = (base_cls, *module_cls.__bases__)
            register_bases(base_cls, module_cls)
```

```py
import inspect
import source, receiving

# Before registering bases
receiving.Foo.get_origin()
-> AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'get_origin'

receiving.Foo.get_origin_bar()
-> AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'get_origin_bar'
```

```py
# register bases
register_bases(source, receiving)
```

```py
# after registering bases
receiving.Foo.get_origin()
-> 'rec'

receiving.Foo.get_origin_bar()
-> 'src'
```

What I need is for the last line to say `'rec'`, indicating that method `get_origin_bar` called `receiving.Bar.origin` instead of `source.Bar.origin`.

Comment: Why can’t you simply link these classes by inheritance, thereby avoid the problem you’ve created for yourself of trying to create parallels? Basically this sounds like an X-Y problem - please explain what is the real problem you’re trying to solve?

Comment: hi thanks for taking the time. not sure I understand your proposed solution. Are you suggesting that that classes in `receiving.py` should inherit from their source classes by importing `source.py` into the module?

Or are you asking why there exists two modules in the first place?

The problem I'm trying to solve is one where one module exists in a Docker env and the other module exists in an API. I'm trying to separate the modules so that anything that can function outside of the docker environment can exist in the API, but the docker classes can still inherit those methods as well.

Comment: To link it back to the example. `source.py` would be the module in the API and `receiving.py` would be the module in the Docker env.

Comment: I’m afraid your explanation doesn’t make any sense, and the diagram doesn’t make sense either - how can Foo inherit from Foo or Bar inherit from Bar?

Comment: `receiving.Foo` inherits from `source.Foo` and `receiving.Bar` inherits from `source.Bar`

Comment: Not according to the code in your question, which is incomplete - so it’s _not_ a minimally sufficent example. Please make the code in your uestion a [mre] with imports, with any missing functions, with some code to try to call these methods.

Comment: Could you explain where you are having trouble with the code? To run, create two modules, one called `source.py` and one called `receiving.py`. Inside `source.py` add the code block from the example under `source.py` and same for `receiving.py`. Then in another environment (e.g. Jupyter notebook) define the function `register_bases` which is provided. Then in the notebook run the code starting with `import inspect` and `import source, receiving`. Then run `register_bases(source, receiving)`.  Then run `receiving.Foo.get_origin()` and `receiving.Foo.get_origin_bar()`.